# How to setup fallback for PUT and DELETE to POST in Laravel

Tags: rest, laravel, put, http-delete

I have to deploy application in Laravel on the shared hosting which doesn't support RESTfull methods like PUT and DELETE.

I believe that there is a way to fallback these http methods in Laravel to POST, but the question is how?

Comment: If your hosting for whatever reasons blocks PUT/DELETE requests (although I really doubt it) making a fallback to POST won't help as the requests won't reach Laravel.

Comment: I think you are right... It seems that I have to change all calls for that methods in JS to POST request and then handle it manually in Laravel instead of RESTfull controller... thanks for take me on the right turn